# counting for specific index sequence

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

i want count index of nodes like this:

```
var serise = [];
serise.push({
    name: foo.eq(0).text(),
    data: foo.eq(1).text(),
    family: foo.eq(2).text(),
})


serise.push({
    name: foo.eq(3).text(),
    data: foo.eq(4).text(),
    family: foo.eq(5).text(),
})


serise.push({
    name: foo.eq(6).text(),
    data: foo.eq(7).text(),
    family: foo.eq(8).text(),
})
```

and slice every sequence of this nodes, for more info 
i have html file just with span and those spans without any class and id,
i can find index of spans like above
now just want slice every index sequence in 3.

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @anand4tech
nothing :) 
look i have sequence of index about 130 ,like above sequence index contains order, like index 0 and index 3 and index 6 all shows name But i want slice theme , from first when index start 0, 1, 2 i want slice this and push two array and go so on 3, 4, 5 slice and push to array i i+1 i+2 slice and push...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look on this solution.

Sample HTML

```
<span>data1</span>
<span>family1</span>
<span>Name2</span>
<span>data2</span>
<span>family2</span>
<span>Name3</span>
<span>data3</span>
<span>family3</span>
```

JS Script

```
 var serise = [];
 var obj=$(document).find('span');// here I used 'document' in your case it might be diffrent
 var spanCount=obj.length;
 var tempObj={};
for (var i=0; i<spanCount;i++){
     tempObj={};
     tempObj.name  =obj.eq(i).text();
     tempObj.data  =obj.eq(++i).text();
     tempObj.family=obj.eq(++i).text();
     serise.push(tempObj);    
 }

alert(JSON.stringify(serise));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HCQxL/1/)**

I still don't know the exact requirement but I just hope the given solution above will help you to solve your problem.